# Style problems: Ui:Repeats with SelectManyCheckBox, with toggleable panels

Tags: primefaces

What I want to have is an easy way for the user to set rights for my software.

I've a Treeset of objects, each object should create 1 toggleable panel in the view. Not every grid will have 3 checkboxes for each line, some will have only 1 or 2.

My object class:

```
public class PermissionCheckBox {

    //the title of the toggleable panel
    private String title;

    //the rights read write delete
    private TreeMap<String, String> rights = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    //the documents which the rights belong to
    private TreeMap<String, String> documents = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public TreeMap<String, String> getRights() {
        return rights;
    }

    public void setRights(TreeMap<String, String> rights) {
        this.rights = rights;
    }

    public TreeMap<String, String> getDocuments() {
        return documents;
    }

    public void setDocuments(TreeMap<String, String> documents) {
        this.documents = documents;
    }

}
```

I've tried this in my view:

```
<ui:repeat var="group" value="#{GroupBean.permissionCheckBoxes}">

    <p:panel header="#{messages[group.title]}" toggleable="true"
        collapsed="true" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">

        <div class="Card">

            <div class="CardBody">

                <ui:repeat var="right" value="#{group.rights.entrySet().toArray()}">

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{messages[right.key]}"  style="float:right"/>

                </ui:repeat>

                <ui:repeat var="document"
                value="#{group.documents.entrySet().toArray()}">

                    <p:selectManyCheckbox style="float:right;" 
                    value="#{GroupBean.selectedPermissions}" layout="responsive"
                    columns="#{group.rights.size()}">

                         <f:selectItems value="#{group.rights.entrySet().toArray()}"
                        var="right" itemLabel=""
                        itemValue="#{right.value} + ';' + #{document.value}" />

                    </p:selectManyCheckbox>

                    <p:outputLabel style="float:left;"
                    value="#{messages[document.key]}" />

                </ui:repeat>

            </div>

        </div>

   </p:panel>

</ui:repeat>
```

As you can see I used float to move everything into the right position. I know that's not very responsive, so I'm searching for a better way to get a design like that. 
I've tried to put the label for the ceckboxes and the selectedItems in two different grids, but then my checkboxes dissapeared.

I also would like to have the toggleable panels in a grid with 2 columns.

[At the moment it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsLvy.png)

Comment: so this works when using the plain jsf counterpart? Or in other words, the tags you added are not the best. This most likely is a plain html/css issue, and by tagging it just PrimeFaces (which I think is not related at all), the number of people able to help you is not optimal. But for client-side html/css issues, you have to post the client-side html, not the serverside facelet/xhtml

Comment: If I only use the jsf counterpart it looks completely crappy: http://i.imgur.com/b3hTo85.png I think it's related to primefaces because normally I should use panel grids to get everything in the right order, so I hoped someone has an idea how to solve the problem in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to use panelGrids now. Rest of the work should be easy for our css guy now :)

```
<ui:repeat var="group" value="#{GroupBean.permissionCheckBoxes}">
        <p:panel header="#{messages[group.title]}" toggleable="true"
            collapsed="true" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
            <div class="Card">
                <div class="CardBody">
                    <ui:repeat var="right"
                        value="#{group.rights.entrySet().toArray()}">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{messages[right.key]}"
                            style="float:right" />
                    </ui:repeat>
                    <ui:repeat var="document"
                        value="#{group.documents.entrySet().toArray()}">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank"
                            layout="grid">
                            <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank"
                                layout="grid">
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{messages[document.key]}" />
                            </p:panelGrid>
                            <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank"
                                layout="grid">
                                <ui:repeat var="right"
                                    value="#{group.rights.entrySet().toArray()}"> 
                                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox style="float:right"
                                        value="#{GroupBean.selectedPermissions[document.value';'right.value]}" />
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p:panel>
</ui:repeat>
```